# Windows authentication and full access pages

Tags: c#, authentication, webforms, web-config, windows-authentication

I am using Windows authentication in my application (web forms), and I am trying to create a page for 401 errors that should be available for all users (authenticated or not).
My web.config file looks something like:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
.....
<location path="pageFor401errors.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

When I run the application on localhost, everything works as expected, but when I publish and deploy on a remote server, I don't have permission to access that page any more (I even tried explicitly accessing that page by modifying the url in browser, and I get a IIS specific error - 401 unauthorized).

Any advices?
By the way, I can't configure the IIS on the server